# Cast with "char", instead of directly NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, casting, nsstring

I have this code

```
self.text = [NSSTring stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite_column_text(init_statement, 0)];
```

I'm wondering why we use the `stringWithUTF8String:` and the `char *` stuff, instead of directly using `NSString` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the sqlite library is not returning `NSString`s, being a C library that knows nothing of Objective C.